# What is the purpose of a power MOSFET in this voltage-peak detector?

Tags: transistors, power, mosfet

I am trying to understand the use of the 3 different power MOSFETS described in this peak-detect circuit. The circuit was designed to measure the voltage peaks from a photomultiplier and the Arduino data-logs and displays the data.

The 3 main circuits from top to bottom are 1. Peak-hold, 2. pulse manipulation, 3. monoflop. My questions concern mainly the peak-hold circuit using the MOSFETs:

Question 1: Since this circuit is low voltage/low current, are power MOSFETs necessary? Why not use transistors NPN transistors or something similar?

Question 2: is the specific choice of IRL3803, IRF4905 and IRL510 important in this circuit? Could these components be swapped with different MOSFETS and achieve the same functionality?

I'm mainly concerned with the use of both IRL and IRF components, since they require 5V and 12V respectively. Is it reasonable to have all IRL components in this circuit?

[image: Circuit in question]

Comment: Looks like a poor circuit to me. At least poorly drawn. My guess they chose whatever was on hand.

Comment: Kartman, thanks for the reply. So what are your thoughts on replacing these MOSFETs with NPN transistors, such as 2Nxxx type?

Answer (score 1):

The MOSFET is used as reset circuit. Why BJT isn't used? Because it would interfere with the sample/reset circuit, as the MOSFET has a insulated gate and low Rdson when triggered - empty the capacitor aka. reset/clear.

However you do need just a very small MOSFET for that purpose.

EDIT:

The bottom circuit seems to be done by someone who has skills in electronics and he knew what he was doing, the upper circuit is made from someone who doesn't really know what he was doing, me neither. Maybe it is useless, so you should rethink on what you need from this circuit.

EDIT 2:

In these days, IMO there are such opamp that could amplify and remove bias even with a single supply.

[image]

If [this](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/more-value-from-absolute-value-circuit-diff-amp.html) holds true, then:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMjaEl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAwDSW.png)</sup>

Comment: So you're suggesting that the MOSFET reset circuit could be done some other way? From what I understand, the top circuit is a combination of peak-hold (using the BC327) and reset/switch using MOSFETs.

Comment: @user273734 I have no idea what is the finction of BC327  and all of MOSFETS in that schematics. If you already have a bottom circuit, then you can simply add the last part of my circuit or search on google: opamp peak detector. The reset could be done via small NFET or MOSFET. The problem would be then if the output is much higher than analog input could handle, you would require to add a series current limiting resistor on output, so that current doesn't exceed the max. of GPIO (Vpeak-Vcc_mcu) / Rseries.